# Is there a way to show slide up panel that shows more data when user slides it up?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

[image: desired functionality]

I would like to have ability to slide up and down the panel to see more data as seen in the image.  Prefer to have cross platform solution. I have tried to use the SlideOverKit but it does not seem to have this sort of ability - or could I be wrong?  Would there be a better solution out there for such a scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many way to achieve a sliding panel, here is one using a `PanGestureRecognizer` for a *swipe* up / down on an absolute layout:

```
<AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="Silver" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,1,1">
<!--        
    Your page's content here
-->
    <StackLayout x:Name="bottomDrawer" BackgroundColor="Olive" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,1.00,0.9,0.04" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <PanGestureRecognizer PanUpdated="PanGestureHandler" />
        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
<!--        
    Your sliding panel's content here
-->
        <Label x:Name="swipeLabel" Text="Swipe me up" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Button Text="Click Me" BackgroundColor="Silver" TextColor="Black" BorderColor="Gray" BorderWidth="5" BorderRadius="20" />
        <Image Source="whome" />
    </StackLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

The `PanGestureRecognizer` handler:

```
double? layoutHeight;
double layoutBoundsHeight;
int direction;
const double layoutPropHeightMax = 0.75;
const double layoutPropHeightMin = 0.04;
void PanGestureHandler(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    layoutHeight = layoutHeight ?? ((sender as StackLayout).Parent as AbsoluteLayout).Height;
    switch (e.StatusType)
    {
        case GestureStatus.Started:
            layoutBoundsHeight = AbsoluteLayout.GetLayoutBounds(sender as StackLayout).Height;
            break;
        case GestureStatus.Running:
            direction = e.TotalY < 0 ? 1 : -1;
            break;
        case GestureStatus.Completed:
            if (direction > 0) // snap to max/min, you could use an animation....
            {
                AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(bottomDrawer, new Rectangle(0.5, 1.00, 0.9, layoutPropHeightMax));
                swipeLabel.Text = "Swipe me down";
            }
            else
            {
                AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(bottomDrawer, new Rectangle(0.5, 1.00, 0.9, layoutPropHeightMin));
                swipeLabel.Text = "Swipe me up";
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

[image]

You can add dragging to the pan gesture by setting the "panel" size in the `GestureStatus.Running` case statement. Something like will get you started:

```
case GestureStatus.Running:
    direction = e.TotalY < 0 ? 1 : -1;
    var yProp = layoutBoundsHeight + (-e.TotalY / (double)layoutHeight);
    if ((yProp > layoutPropHeightMin) & (yProp < layoutPropHeightMax))
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(bottomDrawer, new Rectangle(0.5, 1.00, 0.9, yProp));
    break;
```

[image]

Note: Personally I would use this style of dragging as a prototype only as it is glitchy. I would write a custom renderer per platform to avoid the Forms' layout manager.

Comment: Thank you very much for this idea. I'll try it out but probably still curious if there is something that is able to achieve the same without the 'glitchy' affect :)

Comment: I think I got it working.  But I do have another question - is there a way to re-raise a gesture event?  Meaning that another control is listening for Pan gesture and is not receiving it because the PanGestureHandler event is eating the event.  What's the proper way to reraise the event?

Comment: @JessicaS You can call the another gesture handler from within the first handler and of course change the parameters if needed.

Comment: I don't have control of the other control we were using. So I am still trying to figure out if I could reraise the PanUpdated so that other controls that were listening to it can proceed as needed. Is there a way to figure out how much height is being covered up outside of the Pan event? For example when the control is expanded to figure out that the 120 Height of Listview is being covered by the slider.

Comment: Would it possible to add animation to item being moved off screen such as Swipe to left on listview? If I move item to left I would like to make the item appear off the screen.  Right now I am adding padding to StackLayout but it has no animations